# Why does this simple CSS background colour not work with my jsp files?

Tags: html, css, jsp, background-color

I'm making a (basic) site using css and jsp. However, for some reason, I just can't get this really simple css to work with my jsp page.

Here is code for the css:

```
<style type="text/css">

body {background-color:#6495ed;}

</style>
```

Here is my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blue.css">
<title>Hello ${user}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h2>Welcome to the Admin Panel ${user}</h2></center>

    <form action="verifyredirect" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Verify User" name="submit" />
    </form>
        <form action="removeredirect" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Remove User" name="submit" />
    </form>
        <form action="banredirect" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Ban User" name="submit" />
    </form>
        <form action="unbanredirect" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Unban User" name="submit" />
    </form>
    <form action="changeroleredirect" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Change User Role" name="submit" />
    </form>
    <form action="changepasswordredirect" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Change User's Password" name="submit" />
    </form>
    <form action="viewrequestsredirect" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="View User Requests" name="submit" />
    </form>

    <a href="logout">Log Out</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything is in the right directory. Can anyone point out any problems with the code or help me with the problem? Cheers

Comment: `charset=ISO-8859-1` — Try to avoid legacy character encodings. This century, UTF-8 makes more sense for just about everything.

Answer (score 2):

`<style>` is an HTML element that you can place CSS inside. It must not appear in a CSS file (which should contain *only* CSS and no HTML).

Comment: Thank you! Works. 

That was simple!